# Forward declared enum, default value in .h

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

**Types.h :**

```
enum MyEnum : int8
{
    invalid = -1,
    valid = 0,
}

class TestClass 
{ ... default stuff ...}
```

**MyOtherHeader.h :**

```
enum MyEnum : int8;
class TestClass;

class MyClass
{
    MyEnum Val = -1;
    TestClass* MyObj= nullptr;
}
```

Why can we assign `null` to a forward declare Class Pointer, but can't assign a value of the defined underlying type of the `enum` to a forwarded declared one?

Shouldn't the compiler be able to "deduce" that properly?

TLDR : The question is : Why do we need a work around to assign a default value to the forward declared enum property?

Comment: Define "_can't assign a value_" Do you get a compilation error? If so, copy-paste its text.

Comment: `MyEnum Val{-1};` is accepted by gcc/clang [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24a2e1f599f7f000).

Comment: It doesn't matter that declaration is opaqe. You wouldn't be able to assing `-1` even if the enumerators were seen. Simon's answer has your workaround.

Comment: The question is not, what would be a work around, but why do we need a workaround?

Comment: There are no implicit conversions between integers and enumerators. There never were.

Comment: Are you sure? It's not an enum class, I though enums were initially defined as byte. At some point we got hte ability to define the underlying type. Therefore, it would have guessed it would be able to do implicit conversion? AFAIK an enum is simply a "set of character" that replace a value of the underlaying type.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. And you can easily check it with any compiler that is set to `-pedantic`

Comment: The reason you can assign `nullptr` to a pointer is that it's a pointer; it doesn't matter what type the pointer points to, because `nullptr` is the value of that pointer, not of the thing it points at.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit conversion from an int to an enumeration. As such, you can't [copy-initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) (use `=`) an enum from an int. So even this

```
enum MyEnum : int8
{
    invalid = -1,
    valid = 0,
};

MyEnum e = -1;
```

Would produce the same error. You can either add a cast, or switch to [direct-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) (which a cast is also a form of, here):

```
MyEnum e{-1};
```

The above direct-initializes the variable, though sadly only since C++17. In our particular case you could use it to provide a [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) for your member if you can use a C++17 capable compiler. Otherwise, casting is the only way to provide an initializer for an enumeration from an integer.

Comment: Only list-initialitation is allowed from integer (and only since C++17).

Comment: @Jarod42 - Yes, you are right. I forget what time it is sometimes.